# Why has no one except Bakugo figured out that All Might passed his powers to Deku?

Tags: my-hero-academia

I have been watching *Boku no Hero Academia* for a while now and in my opinion, Midoriya's smash, "power type" way of fighting is so unmistakably and obviously similar to All Might's fighting style.
During the Tournament arc, Battle Trial arc, the 2nd movie (the 2018 movie) and in multiple other occasions, Midoriya has done smashes with the same name and technique as All Might, but yet his classmates don't seem to catch on.

I'm just really curious as to why that is. Cause if All Might has done a smash with the same name and very similar effect (in terms of destructive power and technique), then Midoriya doing the exact same technique should make it obvious that there's a pretty deep connection I guess.

So why has no one else figured out?

Comment: Remember to most people in-universe the idea of transferring quirks is unheard of - so it would be dismissed fairly easily

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bakugo wasnt the only one to notice similarities between Midoriya and All Might. 
Asui pointed out when they were traveling in a bus that Midoriya quirk was like All Might's in season 1 episode 9. Later in season 2 episode 10, before fighting with Midoriya , Shoto Todoroki told Midoriya than since his father was Endeavor who wanted to defeat All Might, if Midoriya had something from All Might (One for All?) he had more reasons to defeat him. The difference between them and Bakugo are

- As pointed in another answer, Midoriya told Bakugo he received his powers from someone else
- Bakugo noticed the enemy of All Might was All for One who had the hability to transfer quirks.
- Bakugo knew All Might met Midoriya (who was quirkless at the time) (and him) when he was captured by a monster in episode 2 or 3 of the first season. After that Midoriya started to show All Might's powers.
- Bakugo saw that Midoriya was crying when All Might consumed all his powers and said "Now is your turn" to the camera.

So in conclusion Bakugo and several others noticed similarities between Midoriya and All Might, but only Bakugo was exposed to additional information who made him conclude with almost certainty that All Might transfered his powers to Midoriya

Answer (score 8):

Taking into account that similar quirks exist in world of MHA, and that All Might is the most popular hero in the world, it is quite easy to imagine people with strength-empowering quirks, who want to be just like All Might, including attack styles. This pretty much covers all similarities between Midoriya's and All Might's powers.

Unlike the rest of Midoriya's classmates, Bakugo has important knowledge to see Midoriya's special circumstances - they have known each other before, and Bakugo is the only one who knows that Midoriya never had a quirk before. This, along with "You are next" (which was not seen by a lot of people) helped him to realize truth.

Comment: In the movie, when Deku was asked what his Quirk was, he called it "power type" - so he didn't specifically name it as "One For All", and that description was apparently sufficient to cover any kind of strength-based Quirk. It probably also helps that Deku's One For All looks a bit different to All Might's - both the way his body gets damaged at full power, and the appearance of Full Cowling.

Comment: Yea i agree with you, Full Cowling is Deku's own version of one for all but in terms of the power of his quirk and his fighting style and the names of his punches, they seemed pretty similar to all mights.

Answer (score 5):

Deku told Bakugo in season 1 episode 8 that someone gave him his quirk (though he didn't say who).  Knowing that Bakugo just had to figure out who gave the quirk.

Without the information Deku willingly told Bakugo, other characters don't know transferring quirks is possible so don't make the connections.